# Wrong package directory (/usr/share/ not /usr/local)

Tags: ubuntu, paths

After upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10 and updating to Texlive 2019 I'm running into errors presumably to do with `latex` (or specifically `lualatex`) not picking up my `/usr/local/` and instead running with `/usr/share/`. Any suggestion what might have gone wrong and how to fix this? Thanks :)

Take this file for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

Plain text.

\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{Link text}.

\textcolor{red}{Red text}

\end{document}
```

If I run `lualatex` on it (in emacs), I get the following error about lualatex and xcolor not being found, but *not* hyperref:

```
ERROR: module 'luaotfload-main' not found:

--- TeX said ---
    no field package.preload['luaotfload-main']
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'luaotfload-main'
    [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'luaotfload-main'
Error in luaotfload: reverting to OT1
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hluatex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))

! LaTeX Error: File `xcolor.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
./test.tex:6: Emergency stop.
```

While `hyperref.sty` is to be located both in `/usr/local/` and `/usr/share/`, `luaotfload-main` and `xcolor.sty` are absent from  `/usr/share/`.

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.st

/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/source/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua

/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
```

Comment: You are using the version of TeXLive installed by Ubuntu packages and not the version of TeXLive that you installed yourself. To use your vanilla installation, add `/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux` in front of the PATH in `/etc/environment`.

Comment: Thank you @PaulGaborit! I added this to my .bashrc and it works fine now! ```export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"```. I guess this means I can also `apt remove texlive*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @PaulGaborit for answering this for me.

I needed to add to my ~/.profile the following:

```
PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
```

I then ran `source ~/.profile`, but in order for emacs to pick up the updated PATH variable, I had to restart my computer.

And then it all works :)

Also: To add this path for all users on the system, see @PaulGaborit's comment.

Comment: +1 It is a solution for a single user. The use of `/etc/environment` is valid for all users of the system.

Comment: Oh, I see, good to know for future reference. Thanks! Also, for single user mode I should have set the PATH in ~/.profile not ~/.bashrc so that my GUIs have access to it, not just the terminal.